# Is there an alternative to Sammy.js that runs on IE < 8?

Tags: routes, client-side, sammy.js

Currently I am using [Sammy.js](http://sammyjs.org/) for client-side routing.

Although it works great in modern browsers, it does not work in IE < 8.
Unfortunately I need it to run in IE 6 and IE 7 as well ...

I've been looking around for an alternative, but not yet found anything as close to Sammy.js as I wished for.

So: Is there an alternative to Sammy.js which works almost the same way (from its API), but successfully supports IE 6 and IE 7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there's an alternative for routing in IE7-IE6: [jQuery BBQ: Back Button & Query Library](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/)